# Connect computers on wifi extender to workgroup

Tags: windows, networking, router, ethernet, workgroup

Good afternoon,
I am trying to connect 4 computers to the same workgroup but I am having some problems. I will try to explain. 
1.- 2 of them are connected via ethernet to the router
2.- 2 of them are connected via ethernet to a TP Link Wifi extender which is also connected via ethernet to the router.
However, I cannot get group 1 and group 2 computers to see each other. I think this might be because of different IP addresses (?)
The router has an IP of 192.168.1.X
When I go the TP admin panel I have the 
LAN - IP: 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.X is what shows up on the PC when running ipconfig)
WAN - 192.168.1.X (which is dynamic)
Could I get help on how to change them for them not to clash (I have tried but failed) or other possible alternatives?
Kind Regards

Comment: You need to set the WiFi extender to Bridge Mode, which will disable DHCP and NAT.

Comment: How can I do it when both routers are connected via ethernet and not wifi?

Comment: It  doesn't make any difference how they are connected. It's a router setting.

Comment: I can only find tutorials on how to do it via WDS (which is wifi). However the wifi reception of router 1 is not great so I wanted to bridge it via ethernet.